# Automate Tableau Parameterised PDF Export

Tags: pdf, tableau-api

Want to automate a dashboard export to PDF at a particular location using a batch file. The dashboard have two parameter say EmpId and Age.

Say there are 10 number of EmpId then it should export 30 different PDF's respectively.
Else an excel file having EmpId and Age column should be get consumed to pass the parameter to dashboard export.

Thanks!

Comment: Add more details. What you do so far?

Comment: I recommend taking a look at the TableauAPI and trying something yourself.http://www.tableau.com/new-features/javascript-api

Comment: Look at tabcmd.exe. It can handle exports with parameters and filters. You then need to programatically generate an email in your favorite programming language, attach the export, and away you go.